# Adding Kivy recycleview to screenmanager breaks example

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to combine [this recycleview example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/recycleview/basic_data.py) with [this screenmanager example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/screenmanager.py) so that the recycleview example can be one of the screens in my app. The app runs but all the control buttons display at the bottom of the UI (They're supposed to be at the top) and are either disabled or obscured, disallowing input. Consequently, the recycleview cannot be populated and/or viewed.

Here's my attempt:

```py
import asyncio
from random import sample, randint
from string import ascii_lowercase

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.recycleview.views import RecycleDataViewBehavior

kv = '''
#:import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#:import BoxLayout kivy.uix.boxlayout.BoxLayout
#:import RecycleDataViewBehavior kivy.uix.recycleview.views.RecycleDataViewBehavior

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    ContactsScreen:
        name: 'contacts'
    MessengerScreen:
        name: 'messenger'
    
<Row@RecycleKVIDsDataViewBehavior+BoxLayout>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    value: ''
    Label:
        id: name
    Label:
        text: root.value

<ContactsScreen>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    rv: rv
    orientation: 'vertical'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        rows: 2
        size_hint_y: None
        height: dp(108)
        padding: dp(8)
        spacing: dp(16)
        Button:
            text: 'Populate list'
            on_press: root.populate()
        Button:
            text: 'Sort list'
            on_press: root.sort()
        Button:
            text: 'Clear list'
            on_press: root.clear()
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Insert new item'
                on_press: root.insert(new_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: new_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        BoxLayout:
            spacing: dp(8)
            Button:
                text: 'Update first item'
                on_press: root.update(update_item_input.text)
            TextInput:
                id: update_item_input
                size_hint_x: 0.6
                hint_text: 'new value'
                padding: dp(10), dp(10), 0, 0
        Button:
            text: 'Remove first item'
            on_press: root.remove()

    RecycleView:
        id: rv
        scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
        scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
        bar_width: dp(10)
        viewclass: 'Row'
        RecycleBoxLayout:
            default_size: None, dp(56)
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: dp(2)
            
<MessengerScreen>:
    

    Button:
        on_release: app.root.current = 'contacts'
        text: 'back to the home screen'
        font_size: 50
'''


class ContactsScreen(Screen):
    def populate(self):
        self.rv.data = [
            {'name.text': ''.join(sample(ascii_lowercase, 6)),
             'value': str(randint(0, 2000))}
            for x in range(50)]

    def sort(self):
        self.rv.data = sorted(self.rv.data, key=lambda x: x['name.text'])

    def clear(self):
        self.rv.data = []

    def insert(self, value):
        self.rv.data.insert(0, {
            'name.text': value or 'default value', 'value': 'unknown'})

    def update(self, value):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data[0]['name.text'] = value or 'default new value'
            self.rv.refresh_from_data()

    def remove(self):
        if self.rv.data:
            self.rv.data.pop(0)

class MessengerScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass

presentation = Builder.load_string(kv)

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return presentation

    def main_runner(self):

        async def run_wrapper():
            # we don't actually need to set asyncio as the lib because it is
            # the default, but it doesn't hurt to be explicit
            await self.async_run(async_lib='asyncio')
            print('App done')
            #self.other_task.cancel()

        return asyncio.gather(run_wrapper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(MainApp().main_runner())
    loop.close()
```

The trouble seems to come from the `<Row@RecycleKVIDsDataViewBehavior+BoxLayout>` directive but I can't seem to fix it no matter where I place it.

Answer (score 0):

You can position the `Buttons` using `pos_hint`, like this:

```
GridLayout:
    id: grid
    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top': 1}
```

Then, you need to size the `RecycleView` so that it is not over the `Buttons`, like this:

```
RecycleView:
    id: rv
    size_hint_y: None
    height: root.height - grid.height
```